# If statement condition fails and skips straight to the else part

Tags: bash, if-statement

my condition always fails and causes it to go to the else statements.

Sample : Jame,Smith,12,100009,2
         Jack, Smith-Potter,9,19998,5
         Jaime-jane,smith,8,92384,3
I got it down to always keeping the most left first name if it's hyphenated and the most right if two last names.  followed by grade, ID, and 2-5 must be replaced with a school. Such as 2 must change to HS, 3 to Middle school and so on. Its start from 2 to 5 and its store in school when the file is passed.

```
#!bin/bash
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=","

while read  First_Name Last_Name Grade Student_Id school
do  
#Keeps the first name before "-" 
FIRSTNAME=$(echo $First_Name | cut -d'-' -f 1)
#Keeps most left name
NAME=$(echo $FIRSTNAME | cut -d" " -f 1)
#Find the spaces between last name and if there are more than one space 
it makes it into one space.
LASTNAME=$(echo $Last_Name | sed -e 's/  */ /g')
other=$(echo $LASTNAME | cut -d' ' -f 2) 
last_Name=$(echo $other | cut -d'-' -f 2)

if [ $school == 2 ]
then
School=$(echo $school | sed -e 's/2/HS/g')
echo "$NAME"."$last_Name" "$NAME" "$last_Name" "$Grade"thGrade 
"$Student_Id" "$School"

elif [ $school == 3 ]
then
School=$(echo $school | sed -e 's/3/MI/g')
echo "$NAME"."$last_Name" "$NAME" "$last_Name" Class"..." 
"$Student_Id" "$School"

elif [ $school == 4 ]
 then
 School=$(echo $school | sed -e 's/4/MO/g')
 echo "$NAME"."$last_Name" "$NAME" "$last_Name" Class"..." 
 "$Student_Id" "$School"

else
 School=$(echo $school | sed -e 's/5/K/g')
 echo "$NAME"."$last_Name" "$NAME" "$last_Name" Class"..." 
"$Student_Id" "$School"

fi


done < $1  
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

The condition fails and it skips to the else statement.

Comment: [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is a pretty helpful site for debugging most bash scripting issues!

Comment: Make sure you quote the variables: if `$school` is empty, the `[` command will blow up. Use `[ "$school" -eq 2 ]` etc. Or more bash-specific `[[ $school -eq 2 ]]` or in an arithmetic expression `(( school == 2 ))`

Answer (score 1):

some corrections in your code :

Use `-eq` instead of `==`

```
if [[ $school -eq 2 ]]
```

Use this after your done :

```
done < <(echo "$1")
```

Your `$NAME` var is not defined/declared

your `$last_Name` var should be `$Last_Name`

Moreover you're better off using switch case statement :

```
case $school in 
2) do_something ;;
3) do_smth_else ;;
4) ... ;;
esac
```

Comment: if [[ $school -eq 2 ]]  then command fi it causes a syntax error.

Comment: Also my case do not work for some reason. I did case $school in 2) do something ;; 3) do something ;; etc it just skips it. never used cases but from what i read this should have work

Answer (score 0):

A lot of duplication in there. You can rely on a simple array lookup instead of `echo|sed`

```
#!bin/bash

schools=("" "" HS MI MO K) # don't need index 0 or 1

while IFS="," read -r First_Name Last_Name Grade Student_Id school
do  
    case "$school" in
        [2-5]) School=${schools[$school]} 
            echo "$NAME"."$last_Name" "$NAME" "$last_Name" Class"..." "$Student_Id" "$School"
            ;;
        *) echo "Unknown school: $school"; ;;
    esac
done < $1
```